# Does existence of those cyclic cardinals imply a kind of Choice?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

Working in $\sf ZF - Fnd$, add the following axiom:

**AntiFoundation**: $\forall x: x \neq \emptyset \to \exists! y: y \in y \land y \sim x$

where "$\sim$" stands for *existence of a bijection*.

In this theory we can easily define cardinality as:

$|X|= \kappa \iff \kappa \sim X \land ( \kappa=\emptyset \lor \kappa \in \kappa)$

> The question is if this would imply any kind of Choice? If yes, what would be that form of Choice?

The backround of this question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3774727/489784) question and in particular to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3774771/489784) answer to it, which asserts that some form of Choice would exist even if its for the empty structure (i.e.; Cardinality).

${{}}$

Comment: My guess would be that any model of ZF is a well-founded part of some model of ZF-Fnd satisfying your new axiom. So no, it probably doesn't imply any amount of choice.

Comment: @Wojowu, that's what I thought also. I've added the context of this question, which is Asaf's answer to my question about structures, but that question was in $\sf ZF$, and this goes beyond it, so I'm not sure if this can manage to avoid choice?